# GCS Storage junit test case how to write

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, java-8, mockito, junit5

Hi I have created a spring boot project with a rest end point which is going to return all the files list inside a cloud storage.
I'm unable to write a junit test case for that. could you please help me on the junit.

## Controller Class

```
@GetMapping("/getFiles")
public List<String> getBucketList() throws IOException {
    Storage storage = 
StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
            .setProjectId("projectId") // project id
            .build().getService();

    return mainService.getFileList(storage);
```

## Service class

```
@Service
public class MainServiceDetails {

public List<String> getFileList(Storage storage) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list("bucketname"); // bucket name

    for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
        list.add(blob.getName());
        System.out.println(blob.getName());
    }
    return list;
}
  }
```

I need minimum 90% code coverage in this one. Could anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got stuck in your unit test but this is how I would test it, I hope this will help you:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private MainServiceDetails mainService;
    @InjectMocks
    private Controller controller;
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Storage> storageCaptor;

    @Test
    public void test() {
         List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("sup1", "sup2", "sup3"); 

         Mockito.when(mainService.getFileList(storageCaptor.capture()))
              .thenReturn(expected);

         List<String> actual = controller.getBucketList();
         
         Storage value = storageCaptor.getValue();
         //verify call to mainService is made with Storage.
         Mockito.verify(mainService, times(1)).getFileList(value);
         //Add some assertions to check if the storage object has the values you expect
         //assertThat(value.getProjectId()).isEqualTo("projectId");
    }
}
```